# UIScrollView architecture

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview, uianimation

I'm trying to create something similar to the [Guardian's Eyewitness app](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/the-guardian-eyewitness/id363993651?mt=8) for iPad. I'm mainly just concerned with the scrollview on the navigation homescreen and how the scaling and carousel effect could be achieved?

If someone knows how this could be coded or knows of sample code producing a similar result, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am using iCarousel to make carousel effects. Please check the source code and samples [here](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel).

Comment: Thanks for providing me with a sample. It's little overkill to what I need (3D) but at least it's a start to something I can work with.